# How can I query the same element of an embedded array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database with documents such as this [one](https://gist.github.com/fastboyz/9b107f5e06b56e15cc8439193da11abe). I want to create an aggregation that will return me only document where `participants.stats.win = true and participants.championId = 57`. I need both condition to be true for the same participant.

```
[{$match: {
  $and: [ { "participants.stats.win": {$eq: true} },
        { "participants.championId": { $eq: 57 } },
         { gameMode: {$eq: "CLASSIC"}}
       ]  
}}, {$project: {
  participants: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$participants",
               as: "participant",
               cond: {
                 $eq: ["$$participant.championId", 57 ]
               }
            }
         }
}}, {$group: {
  _id: null,
  count: {
    $sum: 1
  }
}}]
```

This will return me documents in which a participant.championId = 57 whether or not that said participant won or lost his game.

Comment: post a document here (I know you put up a link for the document, but post it here )

Comment: Hi JBone, I would love to but the document is 1608 lines long, so it would not be practical for reading I think.